# Winforms threading problem, second thread can't access 1st main forms controls

Tags: winforms, multithreading

I have a winforms application, the issue has to do with threading.
Since I am calling 'MyCustomCode() which creates a new thread, and calls the method
'SomeMethod()' which then accesses MessageBox.Show(...).

The problem has to do with threading, since the newly created thread is trying to access 
a control that was created on another thread.

I am getting the error:

Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'TestForm' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

```
public TestForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();


    // custom code
    //
    MyCustomCode();


}

public void SomeMethod()
{

    // ***** This causes an error  ****

    MessageBox.Show(this,   
        ex.Message, 
        "Error", 
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
        MessageBoxIcon.Error
    );
}



private void InitializeAutoUpdater()
{
        // Seperate thread is spun to keep polling for updates
        ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(SomeMethod);
        pollThread = new Thread(ts);
        pollThread.Start();
}
```

**Update**

If you look at this example http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/vanillaupdaterblock.aspx, the method CheckAndUpdate is calling MessageBox.Show(..) that is what my problem is.  I would have thought that code was good to go!

**Funny thing** is that this code was working just fine on Friday???

Comment: could it be because I installed .net 3.5?  Is this a 3.5 'feature'? I doubt it but it is the only explanation!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I update the GUI from another thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-do-i-update-the-gui-from-another-thread)

Answer (score 9):

You cannot acces UI elements from multiple threads.

One way to solve this is to call the Invoke method of a control with a delegate to the function wich use the UI elements (like the message box). Somethin like:

```
public delegate void InvokeDelegate();

public void SomeMethod()
{

    button1.Invoke((InvokeDelegate)doUIStuff);


}


void doUIStuff()
{
           MessageBox.Show(this,   
                ex.Message, 
                "Error", 
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                MessageBoxIcon.Error
            );
}
```

Comment: You should check if invoke is required, e.g. button1.InvokeRequired.

Comment: And if the handle of the form is not yet created, InvokeRequired always return false. That is why SynchronizationContext could be more recommended.

Answer (score 7):

to avoid cross-thread exceptions (InvalidOperationException), here is the code pattern:

```
protected delegate void someGuiFunctionDelegate(int iParam);

protected void someGuiFunction(int iParam)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        someGuiFunctionDelegate dlg = new 
            someGuiFunctionDelegate(this.someGuiFunction);
        this.Invoke(dlg, new object[] { iParam });
        return;
    }

    //do something with the GUI control here
}
```

i agree that this is annoying, but it is an artifact of the fact that windows GUI controls are not thread-safe. The exception can be turned off with a flag somewhere or other, but don't do that as it can lead to extremely hard to find bugs.

Answer (score 3):

To keep things simple you can look into using the [BackGroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class.  This class will provide a framework for to handle your threading and progress notification events.  Your ui thread will handle the progress event and display the error message you pass back.

Answer (score 2):

- Use [Control.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) or [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke.aspx) methods

OR

- Use [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older post, but I recently found an elegant solution to this problem using generics and extension methods. This is a combination of the authors works and some comments.

**A Generic Method for Cross-thread Winforms Access**

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/GenericCrossThread.aspx

```
public static void Manipulate<T>(this T control, Action<T> action) where T : Control
{
    if (control.InvokeRequired)
    {
        control.Invoke(new Action<T, Action<T>>(Manipulate),
                    new object[] { control, action });
    }
    else
    { action(control); }
}
```

This can be called in the following manner, for simplicity I used a label.

```
someLabel.Manipulate(lbl => lbl.Text = "Something");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should **NOT** use BeginInvoke, you should use Invoke, then once you grasp that, you can look into using BeginInvoke if really needed.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
'*******************************************************************
' Get a new processor and fire it off on a new thread.
'*******************************************************************
fpProc = New Processor(confTable, paramFile, keyCount)
AddHandler fpProc.LogEntry, AddressOf LogEntry_Handler
Dim myThread As System.Threading.Thread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf fpProc.ProcessEntry)
myThread.Start()
```

Then in the parent app you have:

```vb
'*************************************************************************
'     Sub: LogEntry_Handler()
'  Author: Ron Savage
'    Date: 08/29/2007
'
' This routine handles the LogEntry events raised by the Processor class
' running in a thread.
'*************************************************************************
Private Sub LogEntry_Handler(ByVal logLevel As Integer, ByVal logMsg As String) Handles fProc.LogEntry
 writeLogMessage(logMsg);
End Sub
```

That's what I do.

Comment: It uses the event message queue to handle inter process communications (thread to parent in this case. :-)  I have an "unknown number" of threads all sending updates to the same parent window.

Comment: I'm in agreement with leppie.

Answer (score 0):

Check for InvokeRequired

Answer (score 0):

I praticularly like a recursive call.

```
public delegate void InvokeDelegate(string errMessage); 

    public void SomeMethod() 
    { 
        doUIStuff("my error message");
    } 


    void doUIStuff(string errMessage) 
    { 
        if (button1.InvokeRequired)
            button1.Invoke((InvokeDelegate)doUIStuff(errMessage)); 
        else
        {
               MessageBox.Show(this,    
                    ex.Message,  
                    errMessage,  
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK,  
                    MessageBoxIcon.Error 
                ); 
        }
    }
```